# Change type information in BSON

Tags: c#, json.net

So I have some BSON data that was stored in a database record that included .NET type information (which was necessary since some of the properties were interfaces and so the concrete type needed to be included). This all worked fine, but now I've had to rearrange some code such that a few classes have been moved into different namespaces. So, for example:

```
class MyClass
{
     public IFoo { get; set; }
}
```

Was orginially serialized with a concrete implementation of `IFoo`:

```
MyNameSpace.Foo
```

But is now:

```
SomeOtherNameSpace.Foo
```

The class `Foo` is identical either way (although it may have some nested properties that have also changed).

This is not a problem for new data, but I need to find a way to convert the old data. The problem is that I can't currently deserialize the old data because it can't find the relevant classes because they have moved. So I'm wondering if there is a way to change the type information that got saved in the BSON without needed to deserialize it? I'm thinking even if I could convert the BSON to JSON, then I could just edit the JSON with some simple string replacement (replace `MyNameSpace` with `SomeOtherNameSpace` for example) and then convert back to BSON and update the database records. Is that something that is possible with JSON.Net? Can I take BSON, convert to JSON (without needing the classes to deserialize it), edit the JSON and then convert back to BSON (with the now updated type information)?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, this seems like one potential solution:

```
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer()
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None,  // make it ignore type handling for now
};
var dyn = serializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(reader);   // to a dynamic object
var str = (string)JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dyn);  // convert to JSON

// search and replace the old name space / assembly with the new
str = str.Replace("MyNameSpace.Foo, MyFirstAssembly",
          $"{typeof(Foo).FullName}, {typeof(Foo).Assembly.GetName().Name}");

// convert back to a dynamic object
dyn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(str);

var ms2 = new MemoryStream();
using (BsonWriter writer = new BsonWriter(ms2))
{
    // write it back to BSON
    serializer.Serialize(writer, dyn);
    // at this point we'd update the database record,
    // but to confirm we can now deserialize the updated data...
    ms2.Position = 0;
    using (var reader2 = new BsonReader(ms2))
    {
        // turn type handling back on
        serializer.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All;
        tempResponse = serializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(reader2);  // success!
    }
}
```

It's a bit messy, but might do in a pinch unless there's a cleaner way to handle this?